# Indexing very slow in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I can't increase the indexing more than 10000 event/second no matter what I do. I am getting around 13000 events per second from kafka in a single logstash instance. I am running 3 Logstash in different machines reading data from same kafka topic.

I have setup a ELK cluster with 3 Logstash reading data from Kafka and sending them to my elastic cluster.

My cluster contains 3 Logstash, 3 Elastic Master Node, 3 Elastic Client node and 50 Elastic Data Node.

```
Logstash 2.0.4
Elastic Search 5.0.2
Kibana 5.0.2
```

All Citrix VM having same configuration of :

> Red Hat Linux-7
>   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz 6 Cores
>   32 GB RAM
>   2 TB spinning media

**Logstash Config file :**

```
 output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["dataNode1:9200","dataNode2:9200","dataNode3:9200" upto "**dataNode50**:9200"]
      index => "logstash-applogs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-1"
      workers => 6
      user => "uname"
      password => "pwd"
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch Data Node's **elastcisearch.yml** File:

```
 cluster.name: my-cluster-name
 node.name: node46-data-46
 node.master: false
 node.data: true
 bootstrap.memory_lock: true
 path.data: /apps/dataES1/data
 path.logs: /apps/dataES1/logs
 discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["master1","master2","master3"]
 network.host: hostname
 http.port: 9200

The only change that I made in my **jvm.options** file is

-Xms15g
-Xmx15g
```

System config changes that I did are as follows:

`vm.max_map_count=262144`

and in /etc/security/limits.conf I added :

```
elastic       soft    nofile          65536
elastic       hard    nofile          65536
elastic       soft    memlock         unlimited
elastic       hard    memlock         unlimited
elastic       soft    nproc     65536
elastic       hard    nproc     unlimited
```

**Indexing Rate**

[image]

[image]

**One of the active data node:**

*$ sudo iotop -o*

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     243.29 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:     357.09 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 5199 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    3.92 K/s  0.00 %  1.05 % [jbd2/xvdb1-8]
14079 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   51.01 K/s  0.00 %  0.53 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
13936 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   51.01 K/s  0.00 %  0.39 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
13857 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   58.86 K/s  0.00 %  0.34 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
13960 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   35.32 K/s  0.00 %  0.33 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
13964 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   31.39 K/s  0.00 %  0.27 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
14078 be/4 elkadmin    0.00 B/s   11.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSIni~h-5.0.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

[image]

**Index Details :**

```
index                         shard prirep state       docs  store
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 11    r      STARTED 30528186   35gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 11    p      STARTED 30528186 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 9     p      STARTED 30530585 35.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 9     r      STARTED 30530585 30.5gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 1     r      STARTED 30526639 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 1     p      STARTED 30526668 30.5gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 14    p      STARTED 30539209 35.5gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 14    r      STARTED 30539209   35gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 12    p      STARTED 30536132 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 12    r      STARTED 30536132 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 15    p      STARTED 30528216 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 15    r      STARTED 30528216 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 19    r      STARTED 30533725 35.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 19    p      STARTED 30533725 36.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 18    r      STARTED 30525190 30.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 18    p      STARTED 30525190 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 8     p      STARTED 30526785 35.8gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 8     r      STARTED 30526785 35.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 3     p      STARTED 30526960 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 3     r      STARTED 30526960 30.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 5     p      STARTED 30522469 35.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 5     r      STARTED 30522469 30.8gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 6     p      STARTED 30539580 30.9gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 6     r      STARTED 30539580 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 7     p      STARTED 30535488 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 7     r      STARTED 30535488 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 2     p      STARTED 30524575 35.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 2     r      STARTED 30524575 35.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 10    p      STARTED 30537232 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 10    r      STARTED 30537232 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 16    p      STARTED 30530098 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 16    r      STARTED 30530098 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 4     r      STARTED 30529877 30.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 4     p      STARTED 30529877 30.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 17    r      STARTED 30528132 30.2gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 17    p      STARTED 30528132 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 13    r      STARTED 30521873 30.3gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 13    p      STARTED 30521873 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 0     r      STARTED 30520172 30.4gb
logstash-applogs-2017.01.23-3 0     p      STARTED 30520172 30.5gb
```

I tested the incoming data in logstash by dumping data into a file. I got a file of 290 MB with 377822 lines in 30 seconds. So there is no issue from Kafka as at a given time I am receiving 35000 events per second in my 3 Logstash servers but my Elasticsearch is able to index maximum of 10000 events per second.

Can someone please  help me with this issue?

**Edit:** I tried sending the request in batch of default 125, then 500, 1000, 10000, but still I didn't got any improvement in the indexing speed.

Comment: What size is your network interface card on the logstash machines and data nodes? Given the numbers you give, it looks like you're maxing out at ~10 Mbs. Can you profile the network usage on your logstash machines?

Comment: @Val I tested the bandwidth between the Logstash machine and one of the Data node using **iperf3** and bandwidth was **2.70** Gbits/sec. So I don't think network is a bottleneck here.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, as that's usually overlooked.

Comment: Also note that if you're using Logstash 5, the `workers` setting in the `elasticsearch` output is deprecated, you should be using pipeline workers instead (i.e. `-w 6` on the command line)

Comment: I am using Logstash 2.4 and Elastic 5.0.2

Comment: Have you tried to point your `elasticsearch` output to the three client nodes instead of the full array of your 50 data nodes. That's the job of the client nodes in the first place. Or do you want to dedicate your client nodes for searching only?

Comment: Also have you tried to play with the `flush_size` parameter which defaults to 500 documents per bulk? Maybe you can squeeze more data in each bulk call.

Comment: I was under the impression that I can send my documents to any of the node in my cluster, and then that node will do the indexing and forward the document to the node having the shard to which it actually belongs to.

Comment: Yes of course you can, except the master node(s) that is, I was just wondering if you tried it.

Comment: Nope, I didn't tried flush_size but  I tried sending the request in batch of default 125, then 500, 1000, 10000

Comment: And what was the outcome of that test? What's the most optimal size in terms of throughput?

Comment: I didn't saw any changes in the indexing rate when I changed the batch size. Do I need to change **flush_size** along with the batch size?

Comment: `flush_size` [is the batch size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-flush_size)... Ok I'm sure we'll figure out

Comment: Have your solve this problem?  how much size of each log?  On my testing result, 3 Node (8 * Intel(R) Xeon 2.20GHz & 32GB(16g for es) memory & RAID 5 disk) , shards:5, replicas: 1,  data size: 300KB,  I can got about 8000 - 12000 /s index rate.

Answer (score 0):

I improved indexing rate by moving to a larger Machines for Data nodes.

Data Node: A VMWare virtual machine with the following config:

```
14 CPU @ 2.60GHz
64GB RAM, 31GB dedicated for elasticsearch.
```

The fasted disk that was available to me was SAN with Fibre Channel as I couldn't get any SSD or Local Disks.

I achieved maximum indexing rate of **100,000** events per second. Each document size is around 2 to 5 KB.